# update en pyMongo de un objeto dentro de otro

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Tengo una api flask con python.
Estoy trabajando con una colección en MongoDB en la que guardo datos de compañías y los bookings de las compañías en un objeto.
Dentro de este objeto de bookings hay otros objetos con un tipo de "id".
Dentro de cada "booking" existe otro objeto data, el cual me gustaria modificar con un updeate.

***Nota el documento ha sido muy simplificado, estoy trabajando con anidaciones.

Esta es la estructura siguiente estructura

```html
"id": 138192381983 (Object id)
"data": (date)
"company_id": 983129831923 (object id)
"bookings": {
    "231232": {
      "name": "",
      "type": "",
      "data": {
          "atributo": '213',
          "atributo2": '3123'
       }
    },
    "20032": {
      "name": "",
      "type": "",
      "data": {
          "atributo": '213',
          "atributo2": '3123'
       }
    }
  }
```

Estoy intentando hacer un update del documento > el objeto bookings> el bokking con "id" 231232 pero no funciona el update.
Os dejo el código.

```html
mongo.db.company.update_one({"company_id": 983129831923, "bookings": 231232}, {"$set":{"salesAbc": {"data": "New Data"}}})
```